# Two subset tables share same primary key from another table as foreign key in a one to one relationship

Tags: database, relationship, relational

I have been trying to find my problem everywhere and I can't find an answer.
(EVERYTHING IN HERE IS AN EXAMPLE)
I have a PRODUCTS table...

PRODUCTS (Parent Table)

**idProduct(PK) *_*__*_*  ProdName *_*___ Prod_Price *_*___  Prod_Type**

```
    1             Top Gun          5.95         Movie
    2        Great expectations    12.45        Book
    3            Fifa 2013         14.99        Game
    4              Ghost           6.75         Movie
```

MOVIES (Child Table 1)

**idMovie(PK) *_*___ idProduct(FK) *_*___ Mov_Lenght *_*___ Mov_Category**

```
    1               1               93             Action
    2               4               87             Drama
```

BOOKS (Child Table 2)

**idBook(PK) *_*___ idProduct(FK) *_*___ idAuthor(FK) *_*___ Book_Number_Pages**

```
    1               2               43                500
```

GAMES (Child Table 3)

**idGame(PK) *_*___ idProduct(FK) *_*___ Game_Category *_*___ Game_Console**

```
    1               3               Sports           XBOX 360
```

The thing is that i want a one-to-one relationship between **PRODUCTS** table and Children tables.
So if a Primary Key on **idProduct** from **PRODUCTS** is on a child table as a Foreign Key, that value won't repeat on the same table or on other two tables (as a one to one but with multiple tables).
I am using MySQL WorkBench as RDBMS what rules I have to specify so that happens.

Thanks for any help

Sorry for my english, not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your foreign keys in the child tables as primary keys, this way you would solve the one-to-many with child tables.

Regarding across child tables, maybe you can use `triggers` to check if the PK existing elsewhere before inserting the record.